# VBA Macro Compile Error

Tags: vba, excel, sum, range

I'm attempting to write a simple VBA macro that will take the active cell's column and the user's input to add a range of cells on a single row together. The range is calculated by adding the integer the user inputs to the active column and that is the end column. The problem is that it gives me a "Compile Error: Invalid Qualifier" when I run it, and gets angry at the 'total' line.

Here is my code. I'm just starting in VBA, but it can't be that hard....right?

```
Sub Food()
Dim first As Variant
Dim last As Integer
Dim days As Integer
Dim month As Range
Dim total As Double
first = ActiveCell.Column
days = InputBox("Days in the month?")
last = first + days
Set month.Value = Range(Cells(first, 4), Cells(last, 4))
total.Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(month)
Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 13).Value = total
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a syntax error.  Try dropping the `.value` on `month` and `total`.

```
Sub Food()
Dim first As Variant
Dim last As Integer
Dim days As Integer
Dim month As Range
Dim total As Double
first = ActiveCell.Column
days = InputBox("Days in the month?")
last = first + days
Set month = Range(Cells(first, 4), Cells(last, 4))
total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(month)
Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 13).Value = total
End Sub
```

If you want to get the value of a range into a variable, you put the `.value` with the range instead of the variable.  For example:

```
x = cells(1,2).value
```

The `.value` property returns the value in a range object.  So it doesn't make sense to use it on a function and will cause excel to throw and error if you try.  It also doesn't make sense to try to set the `month` variable as a value instead of a range since that would just make it an array.  If you want `month` to be an array you would want to set it as a variant instead of a range.

For more information on the `.value` property, see this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value-property-excel